# Backgroud with two different color in VUE

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning VUE for the first time and want to make a page. Here I want to set two different colors connect at left and right on one page in same hight,but what I get is different, unless I add content to the right

I try to the position is relative and float is left and right, it is not worked

And I don't want to use gradient color and use ::before or ::after

```
<template>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      <div class="v1">
        <img src="../assets/v.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="v2">
          <img src="../assets/v.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="v3">
          <img src="../assets/v.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="v4">
          <img src="../assets/v.png"/>              
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="c">
      <div class="v5">
        <img src="../assets/v.png"/>  
      </div>
      <div class="v6">
        <img src="../assets/v.png"/> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  .a{
    margin: 0%;
    /* background: linear-gradient(top, red ,red 50%,blue 50%,blue); */
  }
  .b{
    float: left;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .c{
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
  }

</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tvqK.png)

Comment: Try with adding `display:flex ` to main div

Comment: Really thank you @Dineshkarthik

Answer (score 0):

you must set a display for .main like this:

```css
.main{
  display : flex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been stuck here for a long time, thank you so much